# Fancybox zindex on quicktime video player

Tags: jquery, css, video, fancybox, quicktime

I am tasked with creating a youtube like site. I have a fancybox that i am using to capture log in information. The problem  I have is that when I pop up the fancybox It is placed behind my video player. I have tried playing with the z-index, making the fancybox modal, setting the video players wmode to opaque/transparent,hiding and showing the #T div(worked but restarted the video and looked crappy). None of this has worked. I would like to have the login box centered on top of the video and to be in front of the video. Any help is appreciated.

This is the site in case you want to see the fancybox. I moved it over so that you can tell where it is positioned on the screen. BTW it only happens when you play a video not when you look at a picture. 
http://mmlab.cs.clemson.edu/spring14/g13/metube/media.php?id=1

video object code

```
<style>
div.T {
     z-index:-500!;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:20px;
    left:225px;
}
</style>
<div id ="T">
<object id="asdf" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"  
       codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
       width="854" height="510">
 <param name="src" value="<?php echo $result_row[2].$result_row[1];?>" />
 <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
 <param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
 <param name="controller" value="true" />
 <param name="wmode" value="opaque" /> 
 <!--[if !IE]> <-->
   <object id="asdf1"  data="<?php echo $result_row[2].$result_row[1];?>" width="854" height="510" type="video/quicktime"> 
     <param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
     <param name="controller" value="true" />
     <param name="wmode" value="opaque" /> 
   </object>

</div>
```

fancybox code

```
<style>
.fancybox-skin{

    position:absolute;
    left:150px; 
    top:-100px;
    z-index:10000;
}

#wrap { 
width: 800px;
margin: 20px auto;
z-index:100000;
}

</style>

$(document).ready(function() {
var results = "";
function fan(){
    $.fancybox({
   href : "#login_form_ajax",
   afterShow: function(){
     //$('#T').hide();         
    },
   afterClose : function(){
    $("#login_error").hide();
    //$('#T').show();    
   }
  });   
}

 $("#top-login-button").click(function() {

  var buttval = "<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']))echo 'Sign out';else echo 'Sign in';?>";
  if(buttval == "Sign out")
    window.location.href = 'Logout.php';
      else        
        fan();                  
 });
```

Comment: this `div.T` doesn't correspond to this `<div id="T">`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the z-index on the fancybox overlay not the skin.

Line 180 of your fancybox css file.

```
 .fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8010;
    background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
  }
```

Try change the `z-index` to a much higher number. I can't test it because your player is not showing up.

Also I strongly advise against using a player like quicktime because that is plugin people must install. I recommend using a HTML5 player with flash fallback like [flowplayer.org](http://flowplayer.org)

Comment: I had a hard time finding a video player for IE/Firefox. I'm pretty new to web development. I like the idea of not having to download the plugin. Does flowplayer require html 5? If so I can't use it. Any alternatives?

Comment: @bassxzero no they have a flash version. http://flash.flowplayer.org/ that was the original player before the html5 version. Almost everyone has flash on their pc e.g youtube.  I suggested html5 version so that it's accessible in mobile devices. You can use both. Better than quicktime.